# Alternative to `IJSRuntime.Current`. i.e. How to get `IJSRuntime` in a library referenced from a Blazor Web Assembly application

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Is there some way to get the instance of `IJSRuntime` from a library referenced from a Blazor Web Assembly application?

Microsoft used to have `IJSRuntime.Current`, but [it was removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/347).

I think I can get it with something like `host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>()`, but if that's the case, how do I get the `host`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace AlertServiceLibrary
{
    public class AlertService
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime jsRuntime;

        public AlertService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            this.jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
        }

        public void Alert(string message)
        {
            jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("alert", new[] { message });
        }
    }
}
```

This is a separate library. With only one reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.JSInterop" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note: Use the version relevant to the app your creating.

In your apps `Program.cs`

```
 builder.Services.AddScoped<AlertService>();
```

```
<button @onclick="OnClick">Click Me</button>

@code {

    string message = "hello";

    [Inject]
    AlertService AlertService { get; set; }

    void OnClick()
    {
        AlertService.Alert(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Verax Ill update my answer and show how but your library just need to reference `Microsoft.JSInterop` and the service injected.